# "push()" to an array in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following code, to scan for a Bluetooth device, which for every device found, I want to add the device to an array.

```
devices: Observable<Array<string>>;

bluetoothAdd() {
    this.isScanning = true;
    var plusIcon = this.page.getViewById("add");
    plusIcon.style.opacity = 0;

    var self = this; 
    bluetooth.hasCoarseLocationPermission().then(
        function (granted) {
            if (!granted) {
                bluetooth.requestCoarseLocationPermission();
            } else {
                bluetooth.startScanning({
                    serviceUUIDs: ["133d"],
                    seconds: 4,
                    onDiscovered: function (peripheral) {
                        console.log("Periperhal found with UUID: " + peripheral.UUID);
                        this.devices.push(peripheral); // <- Problem Line
                    }
                }).then(function () {
                    console.log("scanning complete");
                    self.isScanning = false;
                    plusIcon.style.opacity = 1;
                }, function (err) {
                    console.log("error while scanning: " + err);
                });
                this.isScanning = false;
            }
        });
}
```

However, this code throws the following error:

> JavaScript error:
>   file:///app/Pages/Home/home.component.js:99:37: JS ERROR TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.devices.push')

I am working in Typescript, but I know the push function is a JS thing. Not sure how I would do this in Typescript - what have I done wrong?

Comment: This has nothing to do with TypeScript. `this` is not what you expect. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work. You can use `self` though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has nothing to do with TypeScript, it's just normal Javascript rules for **this**.

The problem **this** points to the function you give to **onDiscovered** instead of the class.

You can fix it by using the **self** variable you have defined or by rewriting the code to use arrow functions instead, like this:

```js
devices: Observable<Array<string>>;

bluetoothAdd() {
    this.isScanning = true;
    var plusIcon = this.page.getViewById("add");
    plusIcon.style.opacity = 0;


    bluetooth.hasCoarseLocationPermission().then(
        (granted) => {
            if (!granted) {
                bluetooth.requestCoarseLocationPermission();
            } else {
                bluetooth.startScanning({
                    serviceUUIDs: ["133d"],
                    seconds: 4,
                    onDiscovered: (peripheral) => {
                        console.log("Periperhal found with UUID: " + peripheral.UUID);
                        this.devices.push(peripheral); // <- Problem Line
                    }
                }).then(() => {
                    console.log("scanning complete");
                    this.isScanning = false;
                    plusIcon.style.opacity = 1;
                }, (err) => {
                    console.log("error while scanning: " + err);
                });
                this.isScanning = false;
            }
        });
}
```

Also, as Bhabishya pointed out the type of devices is Observable. That type has no push method defined on it. Instead it will be able to **emit** an array of Devices.

If all you need is an array you should also change the **devices** to be an array of string, instead of an Observable of array of string.

```
devices: Array<string>;
```

You will also have to initialize it.

```
devices: Array<string> = [];
```

Comment: Are you sure about the `this` problem ? In his **onDiscovered** function, `this` should refers to the class, because he his using **arows**, and unlike functions, arrows **share** the same lexical `this` as their surrounding code. There is no new context.

Comment: @PaulBoutes there are no arrow functions in the original post. Adding them is the fix.

Comment: My bad, I didn't see !

Comment: As you note, that code produces the error "property 'push' does not exist on object observable...", so how do I achieve the result I am after? i.e. add each new device that is found to the array?

Comment: Just make it a simple array as suggested in the other answe. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I still get this error with your updated code `JavaScript error:
file:///app/Pages/Home/home.component.js:98:38: JS ERROR TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.devices.push')`?

Comment: well.. that might be because the devices array is not initialized?

Answer (score 2):

You have defined devices as Observable of array `devices: Observable<Array<string>>` and not an array `devices: Array<string>` on which you can call the push() function.